# MySQL get first row for specific value

Tags: mysql

I've been through several solutions here and none seem to work so it's possible that this doesn't match those solutions.

I have a table:

```
    CREATE TABLE answer (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    student_id varchar(255),
    student_answer varchar(255),
    question_id int,
    submitted_time datetime
    );
```

There are situations where students have submitted multiple answers for the same question_id.  I need a way to get the first response that was submitted for a given student.

```
    id  |  student_id  |  student_answer | question_id | submitted_time
    1   |   0993       |  Democracy      |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:22:01
    2   |   0991       |  Democracy      |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:25:02
    3   |   1002       |  Democracy      |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:15:22
    4   |   0991       |  Communism      |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:21:34
    5   |   1342       |  Monarchy       |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:25:43
```

What's needed is a de-duplicated set of data where each student_id appears only once and uses the first response, as noted by the submitted_time.  One would think that the id column should appear in order of submitted_time but that's not necessarily the case.  For example, id 4 was submitted at 18:21:34 with the incorrect answer but the correct answer was submitted at 18:25:02 and entered as id 2.  I'm guessing database lag or something similar but that's not necessarily relevant.  In this case, I would want the following, a row for each unique student_id, sorted by submitted_time.

```
    id  |  student_id  |  student_answer | question_id | submitted_time
    3   |   1002       |  Democracy      |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:15:22
    4   |   0991       |  Communism      |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:21:34
    1   |   0993       |  Democracy      |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:22:01
    5   |   1342       |  Monarchy       |  1911       | 2021-03-21 18:25:43
```

Starting with a base of:

```
    SELECT student_id,student_answer,submitted_time FROM answer GROUP BY student_id;
```

My understanding (and evidence) is that there's no guarantee of ordering there.  However, even adding "ORDER BY submitted_time" still results in both rows for student_id 0991 being returned.  I've tried various subselects and joins and have had no luck.

Thank you for any help.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT answer.student_id,answer.student_answer,answer.submitted_time from answer answer, (SELECT student_id,min(submitted_time) submitted_time FROM answer GROUP BY student_id) min_answer
    WHERE answer.student_id=min_answer.student_id AND answer.submitted_time=min_answer.submitted_time;
```

Haven't tested, but this query should work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried that query before and it deduplicates across the entire table, meaning all question IDs.  I think I'm understanding the query better with your example.  I added a `where question_id = 1911` within the subselect and it seems to have the correct number of rows now.  Is the subselect the correct place to narrow down the results to just one question_id?

Comment: In this case yes. It’s not a typical inner query. We are filtering out & creating a temporary dataset. Then we are using that dataset to filter out original table. So when we add where condition in the sub query, it will return less number rows. And the main join will also happen on less number of rows, You should have index at least on student Id or a composite index on(student Id & submitted time). You can check query plan using “explain” keyword.